# Installing Spark on Hadoop 2.5

Tags: apache2, java, hadoop, scala

I'm running Hadoop on Ubuntu on a Oracle VM on Windows 7. I'm [trying to install Spark](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-installation-on-ubuntu/) on an existing Hadoop installation. For demonstration purposes I do not want to change the existing Hadoop version. Following are the versions of software in my VM.

Ubuntu : 14.04

Java   : Java 1.7 and OpenJDK runtime environment (IcedTea 2.5.2)

Hadoop : 2.5.0

I figured out that for Hadoop I need to install Spark 1.6.2. [When I try to download Spark 1.6](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) it doesn't give me the option for Hadoop 2.5 but has options for 2.4 and 2.6. Will Spark 1.6 work on Hadoop 2.4?

I would like to know the appropriate platform requirements for Spark, Scala and Java to install Spark on Hadoop 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can build spark for any hadoop version by installing [maven](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu/) and follow below steps:

1. [Download spark source code.](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.2/spark-1.6.2.tgz)
2. Run below commands:

   `tar -xvzf spark-1.6.2.tgz`

   `cd spark-1.6.2`

   `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.0 -DskipTests clean package`